# Hows to set Skype shortcut for opening existing instance?

Tags: skype, shortcuts

I'm using Linux for about two years now, but due to my Windows legacy I like keeping icons on my desktop instead of docks, panel shortcuts, etc.

If Skype is already running, pressing the shortcut starts a new sequence rather than opening an existing one. This is kinda cool as you can have two accounts running. But I only have one.

So, my question is whether it is possible to tweak Skype into opening an already existent instance when pressing the shortcut?

Comment: Never mind, I found the answer at: http://forum.skype.com/index.php?showtopic=332401

Comment: Your comment should have been an answer. I took the liberty of doing it for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A user, jackwizard, over at the Skype forums [found a workaround](https://github.com/djeikyb/Skype-single-instance). His script is [mirrored at github](https://github.com/djeikyb/skype-single-instance), and copied here for your convenience.

1. Copy it into a file called skype-single-instance
2. Make it executable. `chmod +x skype-single-instance`
3. Test it. `pkill -9 skype`, then `./skype-single-instance`, then `./skype-single-instance`
4. Make it available system-wide. `sudo cp skype-single-instance /usr/bin/`
5. Change your shortcuts to use it instead of the normal `skype` command.

.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import dbus
import sys
import os

try:
    # Try and set skype window to normal
    remote_bus = dbus.SessionBus()
    out_connection = remote_bus.get_object('com.Skype.API', '/com/Skype')
    out_connection.Invoke('NAME mySkypeController')
    out_connection.Invoke('PROTOCOL 5')
    #out_connection.Invoke('SET WINDOWSTATE MAXIMIZED')
    out_connection.Invoke('SET WINDOWSTATE NORMAL')
    out_connection.Invoke('FOCUS')
except:
    os.system("skype")
    sys.exit()
```