# Can I do anything about these Skype bugs?

Tags: skype, microsoft

Skype has been bugged for me in every install of Ubuntu I've had. And it's always the same bugs:

The icon still shows up in the taskbar when I'm watching fullscreen video.
When I try to open Skype while Skype is already running, it tries to start a new instance, instead of accessing the process that already exists.

These seem like pretty ridiculous bugs. I figured they would be fixed quickly. But they haven't. And now that Microsoft owns Skype... Is there any hope that Skype is going to be fixed? Has Microsoft ever released any software that runs on Linux? I hear ASP won't even run on a Linux server...

Is tehre anything I can do to not let these bugs bug me?

Comment: You need to redirect your question to the company that runs the skype service and provides the skype software. Skype is not free software and uses no known standard protocol. It is a black box which no one on this site knows anything about.

Comment: OH yeah there are many annoying bugs... I am trying to figure out how to get Skype to work in my Unity. After closing it disappears !

Comment: @Duli-chan: To [keep the Skype icon in the systray](http://pricklytech.wordpress.com/2011/04/30/ubuntu-11-4-natty-customizing-the-notification-area-in-unity/) look at the link.

Comment: Yeah I knew it but not working ... Check my question - http://askubuntu.com/questions/55000/kget-skype-and-vuze-are-not-showing-up-in-my-panel

Comment: @Daniel you still have a lot of discussion stuff in your question. It's a worthy and interesting discussion, but it belongs at http://ubuntuforums.org, not here. Also, one question one answer works best..

Comment: You're asking a lot of questions in here. A lot of them are speculations that can't be answered objectively. If you have certain issues you're trying to seek solutions too I suggest you ask just those. [djeikyb](http://askubuntu.com/questions/55742/can-i-do-anything-about-these-skype-bugs/55765#55765) has already pointed you to some resources on this site which address some of your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are existing questions and answers for your problems.

[How can I remove the Skype panel icon?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/7479/can-i-remove-the-skype-panel-icon)

[Hows to set Skype shortcut for opening existing instance?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/48405/hows-to-set-skype-shortcut-for-opening-existing-instance)

Comment: I didn't want to remove the icon, I just want it not to show up in fullscreen video, and stuff... And I guess the second is as good a workaround as I can hope to get.

Answer (score 2):

It is really quite simple. Stop using Skype.

Comment: A very good answer! :)